# Объединение двух массивов с заменой значений на php

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите как объединить два массива

```
$arr1 = [0 => 'Один', 1 => 'Два', 2 => 'Три']; //где ключи это id из таблицы БД, которые могут меняться, а значения ключей не меняются
```

и

```
$arr2 = ['One','Two','Three']; //где элементы это просто текст
```

так, что бы значения ключей первого массива стали ключами нового вложенного массива, а значениями были пара ключ первого массива и значение второго массива

```
$result = ['Один' => [0 => 'One'], Два => [1 =>'Two'], Три => [2 => 'Three']];
```

При одинаковых id всё работает

```
    $arr1 = [0 => 'Один', 1 => 'Два', 2 => 'Три']; 
    $arr2 = [0 => 'One', 1 => 'Two', 2 => 'Three'];
    $res = $arr1 + $arr2;
    foreach($arr1 as $i=>$k){
       $result[$k][$i] = $res[i]
    }
    return $result;
```

Но если будет так

```
$arr1 = [10 => 'Один', 11 => 'Два', 12 => 'Три']; 
$arr2 = [0 => 'One', 1 => 'Two', 2 => 'Three'];
```

То результат не верный.

Comment: не верный? а какой вы ожидаете получить?

Comment: что бы значения ключей первого массива стали ключами нового вложенного массива, а значениями были пара ключ первого массива и значение второго массива

$result = ['Один' => [0 => 'One'], Два => ['Two'], Три => ['Three']];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно вас понял

```
$arr1 = [10 => 'Один', 11 => 'Два', 12 => 'Три'];
$arr2 = [0 => 'One', 1 => 'Two', 2 => 'Three'];
$result = [];


foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
  $result[$value][$key] = array_shift($arr2);
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: В результате получается
`
$result = [ Один => [0 => One] , Два => [0=> 'Two'], Три => [0=>'Three']]
`
Вместо нужного
`
$result = [ Один => [10 => One] , Два => [11=> 'Two'], Три => [12=>'Three']]
`

Comment: Поправил, старайтесь более развернуто описывать вопрос

Answer (score 0):

попарно надо сложить-то или как? `array_combine` обычно используется для формирования массива по готовым ключам и значениям

```
$values = array_combine(array_keys($arr1), $arr2);
$result = array_combine($arr1, array_chunk($values,1,true) );
```

Comment: Так тоже верно, но отчасти. Мне результирующий массив в селект выводить и вложенный нужно было получить для вывода категорий.

Comment: @dymsonn да, не проверил код. Исправил.